# Find command: name in list

Tags: bash, find, array

I have a file with a list of names:

```
john
paul
ringo
george
...
```

Then I have a bunch of files with a lot of different names:

```
maria.iso
jose.iso
pablo.iso
john.iso
jack.iso
jane.iso
...
```

I want to execute a `find` command that outputs only the files that have the same name as one of the file list, or none if there's no match. In my example:

```
john
```

Something like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.iso" (in array)
```

But I don't know if it's possible or where to start if it is.

So far my only idea is to code a for loop, but that seems ugly and very inefficient.

Thanks

Comment: what about `find . -type f -name '*.iso' | grep -f your_list`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `readarray` to read the names into an array `names`. Then loop each of the elements in the array to do the `find` command.

```
readarray names < names.txt

for n in ${names[@]};do
    find . -type f -name "${n}.iso"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do "or" tests in `find`: `find . -name a -o -name b ...`.

So, modifying your file to add the switches, and using `xargs` to build the find command:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print "-o"}; {print "-name", $0".iso"}' input-file | xargs find .
```

For a sufficiently small list, this should run only one `find`. If you have blanks, quotes or other special characters in the filenames, consider using records separated by the ASCII null character (GNU sed can be used to modify the input in that case).

Comment: `?`, `*`, `[` and backslash would also need to be escaped for `find`'s `-name`.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier with `zsh`:

```
names=(${(f)"$(<name-list.txt)"})

ls -ld -- **/(${(~j[|])names}).iso(D)
```

Where:

- `$(<file)` ksh-style operator that expands to the content of `file`
- `f` parameter expansion flag the splits on line`f`eeds, so we store in `$names` the lines of `name-list.txt`
- `j[|]`: joins the elements of the arrays with with `|`
- `~` treats that `|` as a glob operator (here for alternation) instead of a literal `|`.
- `**/`: recursive globbing (search in any level of subdirectories).
- `(D)`: glob qualifier that enables `dotglob` (include hidden files and search inside hidden dirs like `find` would do) for that one glob.